# How to make System notifications use Chrome notification system?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, notification

Everywhere I read about how to make chrome to use system notification (chrome desktop notification to notifyOSD).
I'm just wondering if there is a way to make the opposite:

**Is it possible to make my Ubuntu system to use chrome notification system?**
For example if`lib-notify` sends a notification about battery low, it shows in a Chrome notification.

Comment: I highly doubt it. This would mean that your system would have to start up Chrome (or Chromium) and then pass in the notification through some API.